# Why is my popup styling messed up?

Tags: jquery, css, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup to create a popup form. I copied and pasted the code from the "Popup with Form" demo [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), resulting in the following test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/magnificPopup.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'inline',
                    preloader: false,
                    focus: '#name',

                    // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
                    // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
                    callbacks: {
                        beforeOpen: function() {
                            if($(window).width() < 700) {
                                this.st.focus = false;
                            } else {
                                this.st.focus = '#name';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- link that opens popup -->
        <a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Open form</a>

        <!-- form itself -->
        <form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <fieldset style="border:0;">
                <p>Lightbox has an option to automatically focus on the first input. It's strongly recommended to use <code>inline</code> popup type for lightboxes with form instead of <code>ajax</code> (to keep entered data if the user accidentally refreshed the page).</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="" type="email">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="" type="tel">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
                        <textarea style="width: 139px; height: 54px;" id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, while the code from the demo displays like this:

[image]

The code from my test page displays like this:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Could you please make a jsFiddle with external js and css for helping us helping you ?

Comment: try this i your css :  `#test-form {display:block;//or inline-block}`

Comment: You need to add a background color to the container. Try this `.white-popup-block {background: #fff;}`

Comment: @anpsmn - that does help somewhat, although it still looks different than the demo... Isn't the formatting built into the magnific css file?

Comment: @froadie Just looked at the demo on their site (Popup with form). They have applied a custom css for the form. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qho896b7/). If you go to their demo site and click on the demo for popup with form and inspect, you will see `.white-popup-block` has styles which I guess is not included in the CSS.

Comment: @anpsmn - thanks! Not sure why they made a demo with code not included in the CSS or clearly outlined in the demo. I'll add those css styles to our local magnific css file. If you post as an answer I'll accept

Comment: @froadie yeah strange they haven't specified clearly about it. I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have applied a custom CSS for the form.If you go to their [demo site](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup) and click on the `Open Form` under `Popup with form` and inspect, you will see `.white-popup-block` has styles which is not included in the [default CSS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css). You need to apply those styles to the container.

```
.white-popup-block {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qho896b7/)

Answer (score 1):

> The two `js` and `CSS` you have included regarding **magnific-popup**
>   dont contain any CSS styling for the FORM so its our responsibility to
>   style the `form` as we wish

1. I have addached the fiddle link without any css for form so it show's plain

[Plain Form](https://jsfiddle.net/pm3v1jwq/)

2, Now i have added Jquery mobile to the below JsFiddle now look how the form looks.

[JqueryMobile Form](https://jsfiddle.net/pm3v1jwq/1/)

You have to style the form content.

Comment: Where does the formatting of the demo come from? I thought that's what the magnific css file is for.

Comment: @froadie No magnific CSS file contains only the CSS required to create a overlay with background color and extra and the content that is the text or form or anything which we use inside the POPUP is upto the user to design as he wishes.