# How can I pull my popup content from an external file?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup to create a popup form. Everything works fine as long as I leave it inline, but if I try to move the form to an external file, I can't seem to load it in a popup.

As an example - taking the code from the "Popup With Form" demo [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), I create the following file, which works as expected. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qho896b7/) (courtesy of @anpsmn in response to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936959/why-is-my-popup-styling-messed-up)).

However, I realized that I would like to use the same form in multiple places, so I tried to move the form to an external file. I called it MagnificForm.cfm (I will be working with ColdFusion code in my real form) and it contains just the form element:

```
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
     <h1>Form</h1>
     <fieldset style="border:0;">
         <p>Lightbox has an option to automatically focus on the first input. It's strongly recommended to use <code>inline</code> popup type for lightboxes with form instead of <code>ajax</code> (to keep entered data if the user accidentally refreshed the page).</p>
         <ol>
             <li>
                 <label for="name">Name</label>
                 <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text">
             </li>
             <li>
                 <label for="email">Email</label>
                 <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="" type="email">
             </li>
             <li>
                 <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                 <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="" type="tel">
             </li>
             <li>
                 <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
                 <textarea style="width: 139px; height: 54px;" id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
             </li>
         </ol>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Then I tried to modify the link that opens the pop-up to point to the file:

```
<!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="magnificForm.cfm">Open form</a>
```

This doesn't work - results in an empty popup.

I also tried pointing to the form element specifically:

```
<!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="magnificForm.cfm#test-form">Open form</a>
```

I also tried renaming the file to magnificForm.html. But I can't seem to get the content of the external file to load in the popup.

Comment: jquery.load might be what you need: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to change `type: 'inline'` to `type: 'ajax'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the 'ajax' tip.

This may be dumb but incase anyone else comes here to see this solution and is using the example code and it just seems to not be working make sure you remove the class 'mfp-hide' from the example form.  That class will keep the form hidden even if the page is in fact popping up. Hopefully that saves someone the 15 minutes I wasted.

Comment: Please do not post "thanks" as an answer to the question. Also, this does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).